# Clear Contents of a Column

Tags: vba, excel

How would I clear the contents of a column from cell A3 to cell __ where __ represents the last entry in the column (assuming there are no empty spaces between entries).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
range("A3", Range("A" & Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)).Delete
```

That will delete A3 through the last cell in column A, regardless of any blanks in the column.

```
range("A3", range("A3").End(xlDown)).Delete
```

That will delete from A3 down to the first blank cell after A3 in column A.

**EDIT:** Fixed the first code snippet so it only deletes cells in column A.

Comment: Thanks for both of the options!  I am learning the value of "SpecialCells"

Comment: I used this and strangely, it cleared the last used column every time, no matter what column I specified. Still trying to find out why.

Comment: WARNING I tried this, and it cleared all rows, not only the column A...

Comment: @TBG Sorry about that, I fixed that first snippet so it only deletes cells in column A.

Answer (score 11):

```
Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Clear
```

Using .Delete will actually delete the cells, shifting up any cells that might appear after this list (separated by a blank cell). If you just want to clear the contents, .Clear is a good way to go.

Comment: Works like a charm ! I used `.ClearContents` but that's the same I suppose

Answer (score 2):

I would use a vbNullString, because it's slightly faster and works efficently on huge amount of data worksheets.

Paste 'nothing' from A3 to the first blank cell in column A:

```
Range(Cells(1,3), Cells(Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row,1)).Value = vbNullString
```

Paste 'nothing' from A3 to the last cell in column A:

```
Range(Cells(1,3), Cells(Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlTypeLastCell),1)).Value = vbNullString
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results with this:

```
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Name")
Count = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

Range("AC2:AC" + CStr(Count)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```